# EF Core exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfewR.png)

Attached is the error display when I try to configure the table Product.

public class SIPDigitalBaseEntities : BaseDbContext
{
public SIPDigitalBaseEntities(DbContextOptions options)
: base(options)
{ }
public DbSet UtilityMaster { get; set; }
public DbSet ProductMaster { get; set; }

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new BatchRunMap());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new UtilityMasterMap());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ProductMap());


     }
```

}

Comment: Please share all you code, and provide errors as test not images

Comment: ERROR: Cannot use table 'Product' for entity type 'Product' since it is being used for entity type 'Product' and there is no relationship between their primary keys.                                                                     

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot use table 'Product' for entity type 'Product' since it is being used for entity type 'Product' and there is no relationship between their primary keys.

Comment: namespace SIPDigital.Base.Entities
{

    public class SIPDigitalBaseEntities : BaseDbContext
    {
        public SIPDigitalBaseEntities(DbContextOptions<DbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        { }
        public DbSet<UtilityMaster> UtilityMaster { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> ProductMaster { get; set; }
      
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new UtilityMasterMap());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ProductMap());
        }
    }
}

Comment: namespace SIPDigital.Base.DataClass
{
    [Table("Product")]
    public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        public long ProductId { get; set; }

        public string CountryCode { get; set; }
        public int      BusinessRegionID { get; set; }
        public string BusinessGroupCode { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }